# Return value after snapshotChanges().subscribe in firebase list

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I created the following function in order to get the data from a firebase table, including the record's key:

```
  fetchUsers() {
    this.firebase.list('users').snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.userList = [];
        res.forEach(element => {
          var user = element.payload.toJSON();
          user["$key"] = element.key;
          this.userList.push(user as User);
        });
      });
  }
```

how can i return the userList array when the function is called?

Comment: Where do you have this `fetchUsers` method in a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an observable of an array and then subscribe to it.

```
fetchUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.firebase.list('users').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res.map(element => {
          let user = element.payload.toJSON();
          user["$key"] = element.key;
          return user as User;
        });
    }));
}
```

And then you can subscribe to this method from where ever you calling it.

```
this.usersSubscription = this.dataService.fetchUsers.subscribe(users=> {

   this.users = users;
});
```

Remember to unsusbscribe on onDestroy.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.usersSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Checkout this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-simple-service-evmjxz?file=app/simple.service.ts)

Comment: thanks for the answer Senal, this returns the error "Cannot find name 'res'"

Comment: There was a typo on my answer, an extra `)`.I have updated the answer with a working stackblitz may be that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Don't `subscribe` and instead `map` to the value you want to return, this will return an `Observable` from `fetchUsers` which you can then subscribe to via `this.fetchUsers.subscribe((...) => ...)`:

```
fetchUsers() {
    return this.firebase.list('users').snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map((res) => {
        this.userList = [];
        res.forEach(element => {
          var user = element.payload.toJSON();
          user["$key"] = element.key;
          this.userList.push(user as User);
          return this.userList;
        });
      }));
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Chrillewoodz, this returns the error "Cannot find name 'res'"

Comment: @Elias there was a ( missing as well as the return statement.

Comment: thank you very much, both answers worked after your corrections